# register hardware back button based on routed condition Ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic4

As my Ionic4 application starts, it comes to login page and once user enter credentials and log in. It will redirect to tabbed interface `ion-tabs`.

For login, I have `localhost:8100/#/login`.

For Request, I have `localhost:8100/#/tabs/requests`

For Inbox, I have `localhost:8100/#/tabs/inbox`

For Outbox, I have `localhost:8100/#/tabs/outbox`

Request, Inbox and Outbox page comes in Tabbed Interface. Whereas Login page is separate and it's an entry point of application.

I want to register hardware back button in such a way that if it's in login page and hardware back button is pressed then it should close the application but if application is in tabbed interface ( routes from /tabs/... ) and hardware back button is pressed then it should raise an alert box that "Are you sure want to go back" or something.

I have tried this example but it didn't work for me.

https://medium.com/@reviloera.../ionic-framewok-4-hardware-back-button-9b45df233414

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: I've updated the question

Answer (score 0):

use

```
  this.subscription = this.platform.backButton.subscribe(()=>{ 
      // Check with Router what you want to do here
      navigator['app'].exitApp(); 
  });
```

Comment: While your code may provide the answer to the question, please add context around it so others will have some idea what it does and why it is there.